# Regular expression removing special characters from the end

Tags: java

Given i have a string of = `RUB_CURR_29JAN2021_061420210106999.txt`

I am going with indexof approach to remove all characters, final output of string should be `RUB_CURR_`

I have written the `script result.substring(result.indexOf("_"));` but this will only remove characters from the first index of _  which will result of CURR_29JAN2021_061420210106999.txt, is there any way i could remove from the last two `_` instead of the first `_`

Answer (score 3):

Overload the indexOf method

```
str.substring(0, str.indexOf("_", str.indexOf("_") + 1) + 1);
```

Comment: I adjusted your code so it actually includes the last `_`. So in the end the result is `RUB_CURR_`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following to read through te String one character at a time (if it is 100% that the given String contains two '_' characters):

```
String newResult = "";
int underscoreOccurance = 0;

for ( int index = 0; index < result.length(); index++ ) {
    newResult = newResult + result.charAt(index);

    if ( result.charAt(index) == '_' ) {
        underscoreOccurance++;
    }
    
    // You can also prefer to use underscoreOccurance == 2
    // or underscoreOccurance >= 2
    if ( underscoreOccurance > 1 ) {
        index = result.length(); // end the for loop when two underscores are read
    }
}

result = newResult;
```